# Entity reference multi-select

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to make an entity reference field a multi-select options select but I can't seem to find out how to make that happen. Any help is appreciated. Below is the code I'm using.

```
$fields['some_field'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Some Field'))
  ->setDescription(t('This is a field.'))
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'other_entity')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
  ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'author',
    'weight' => 0,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'options_select',
    'weight' => 0,
    'settings' => [
      'options_select' => 'multiple',
      'placeholder' => '',
    ],
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
  ->setRequired(FALSE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately this was answered in a different but similar [question I asked](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273582/display-entity-as-options-select-multi-select). The answer is the code below attached to the field in my entity.

```
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;

->setCardinality(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can by using [BaseFieldDefinition::setCardinality](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21BaseFieldDefinition.php/function/BaseFieldDefinition%3A%3AsetCardinality/8.2.x)

> Sets the maximum number of items allowed for the field.

<strike>By adding:</strike>

```
->setCardinality(0) 
// 0 means unlimited. Put 3 if you only want to allow up to 3 values
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I added it to the entity but the form it still displays it as a drop down and not a multiple select list. I assume there is an setDisplayOptions option I need to apply to make this happen? After looking through the core code I couldn't seem to narrow that down.

Comment: ->setCardinality(0) Didn't work for me or at least it didn't produce the outcome I was looking for. I asked a similar question but rather on the form display side of things and someone responded with the following similar answer that worked.


    ->setCardinality(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED)

Comment: @themantimeforgot in the link I provided, I actually missed reading `Possible values are positive integers or FieldStorageDefinitionInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED.`. In D7 zero was used for unlimited, but clearly no longer the case for D8.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes a lot of sense. I appreciate the help, it definitely got me going in the right direction so it definitely helped.