# Display entity as options_select multi-select

Tags: 8, entities, forms

Below is my code for the view. I have tried multiple = true, multiple_values=true, multiple = multiple. None have worked.

```
->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'options_select',
    'weight' => 0,
    'settings' => [
        'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
        'size' => '60',
        'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
        'placeholder' => '',
    ],
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `options_select` widget will automatically be multi-select if the cardinality of the field is multiple. Make sure your field is created as such, e.g.

```
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;

...

$fields['foo'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ...
  ->setCardinality(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED)
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'options_select',
    'weight' => 0,
    'settings' => [],
  ])
  ...
```

Incidentally, `options_select` has no settings, so you can provide an empty array instead of the autocomplete settings you're currently using.

Comment: while adding FieldStorageDefinitionInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED, I am getting error like Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'temp.modulename__foo' doesn't exist, @Clive any idea about this?